# Mongo complex aggregate (condition based on group count)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Id need a mongo aggregate that given the sample data:

```
{
    'employeeNumber': '1',
    'companyId': '1',
    'role': 'D',
    'dateHired':ISODate("2013-11-26T00:00:00.0Z")
    ...
}
{
    'employeeNumber': '1',
    'companyId': '1',
    'role': 'S',
    'dateHired':ISODate("2013-11-26T00:00:00.0Z")
    ...
}
{
    'employeeNumber': '1',
    'companyId': '2',
    'role': 'D',
    'dateHired':ISODate("2013-11-26T00:00:00.0Z")
    ...
}
{
    'employeeNumber': '2',
    'companyId': '1',
    'role': 'D',
    'dateHired':ISODate("2013-11-26T00:00:00.0Z")
    ...
}
```

queries for a given companyId (e.g. companyId = 1, using match stage probably) and would return something like:

```
{    
    'employeeNumber': '1',
    'companyId': '1',
    'role': 'D','S'
    'dateHired':ISODate("2013-11-26T00:00:00.0Z")
    ...
}
```

notice that

```
{    
    'employeeNumber': '1',
    'companyId': '2',
    'role': 'D'
    'dateHired':ISODate("2013-11-26T00:00:00.0Z")
    ...
}
```

is not returned.

Ideally it would return the whole object as the collection has 10/12 fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) you will not get exact expected output but you can get output like following:

```
{ "role" : [ "D" ], "employeeNumber" : "2" }
{ "role" : [ "S" ], "employeeNumber" : "3" }
{ "role" : [ "D", "S" ], "employeeNumber" : "1" }
```

And the query will be like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
    _id: "$employeeNumber",
    "role": {
        "$push": "$role"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "employeeNumber": "$_id",
    "role": 1,
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

**Edit** After question edit:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
    _id: {
        employeeNumber: "$employeeNumber",
        "companyId": "$companyId"
    },
    "role": {
        "$push": "$role"
    },
    "dateHired": {
        $last: "$dateHired"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "employeesNumber": "$_id.employeeNumber",
    "comapnyId": "$_id.companyId",
    "role": 1,
    "dateHired": 1,
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

Comment: mmm... that might do... what about if I have other fields I want to include in the result?

Comment: @Angelo If you want to add field as an array then add it like `role` and add it projection too. It will be better if you modify your question and add document structure with all fields.

Comment: so each field needs to be "declared" in the previous stage? And what if I add a match stage? will the fields I didn't use in the match be available in the group stage?

Comment: In group you can use any field. But here, projection works on $group result so you can use fileds that are defined in $group.